# Traversal on a tree with duplicated subtrees

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, traversal

I have a simple recursive post-order traversal on a tree that prints all the possible paths. The problem is that it takes a lot of time.

I would like to use the property of my tree in order to save the traversal time.
the property is that I have duplicated subtree, in the example below, the subtree with the head 1 appear in the tree 3 times.

```
          10
  /        |        \
 5         15        1
 /\        / \      / \
2  1      1   6    3   8
  / \    / \
 3   8  3   8
```

I looking for improvement for my traversal that skips the sub trees that already been passed.
The idea is to store every subtree that i've passed, but I couldn't fit it to the post order algorithm.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Think about this. When you traversing the tree, how would you know a subtree has appeared before without traversing it? So try to reorganize your tree and make marks on the repeated subtrees. It maybe help.

Comment: Are the node-ids always associated with the same sub-tree? For example, if you see a node with id 1, can you be certain that it always represents the same subtree (1, 3, 8) in your example? In that case, I would build a hash table of all traversed node ids. And for every node you are going to inspect I would first ask the hash table whether you have seen that node already and hence can skip it including its entire subtree.

Comment: yes, every node id is associated with one subtree. I tried your idea but because I have to print all the paths in the tree, I didn't know how to fit the idea that I already pathed in that subtree to the algorithm.

Comment: you seem to actually have a DAG, not a tree. So you need to change your tree traversal into a full DFS by adding a data structure to keep track of the visited nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash set to store which nodes have been visited, and for each node you visit, check if it's already been visited: if not, add it to the visited set, and proceed as usual, otherwise return.

Comment: But this assumes that if you encounter a root node that's identical to one you've already encountered, you should return. In actuality what the question asker wants is that the entire subtree is identical to one that has already been traversed. Consider the case where root = 1, left = 2, right = 3. You traverse that tree, and then later you encounter a subtree where root = 1, left = 2, right = 4. With what you propose, the algorithm should skip the latter subtree after encountering 1 for the second time, when in reality it shouldn't because right=4, not 3, so the subtrees are different.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks, I didn't see that comment. In that case I rescind my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your program allows this change....Since we can not know if a subtree has appeared before when traversing, one possible way is to reorganize your tree as following to share the repeated subtree.

```
          10
  /        |        \
 5         15        1
 /\        / \      / \
2  1 ------   6    3   8
  / \     
 3   8
```

Comment: what do you mean by "share"? notice that the subtree (1,3,8) appear 3 times in the example

Comment: if you connect 10 to the leftmost (1,3,8) subtree it wouldn't be a 3 anymore cause you'd get a cycle.

Comment: @Kfozli If 3 identical subtree(1, 3, 8) apear 3 times, by share is to keep only one copy of the subtree, then let nodes 5, 10...point to the copy.

Comment: @Adrian yeah..it may result in a cycle. I think it matters not...after all  there has to be a way to know if a subtree has been visited.

Comment: There is, it's just not this way. This way we could convert our tree into a graph and it's probably not what we want. The best way would be to use a hash table to store visited nodes, as described above.

Comment: @Adrian But in this way not only can we save storage, but also programming effort..

Comment: Did you even read what I wrote? Your solution changes the data structure from tree to graph, which is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

> that prints all the possible paths

I think this is the main problem. The running time of your program is linear in the amount of data to output, roughly for each step in tree your program does it should output at least one symbol. So you have no room for speedup here as long as you keep the required output the same (i.e. as long as you require all paths to be output), you just can not have an algorithm that is faster than `O(R)`, where `R` is the total size of output you need to produce.

In fact, most probably the main bottleneck is output itself (console or disk performance is usually much worse than just walking in memory), so I think that if you profile your program, you will find that 90% of time is spent in output. Therefore not only you can not get a better asymptotically solution, you can not get a faster solution at all. (Except that if you optimize the output itself, but that's a different question.)

However, if you do not need to *print* all paths, but process them in some way — for example, count how much of them exist, or find the longest path, etc — then your solution can greately benefit from the fact that you have repeating subtrees. Actually, this means that you have not a *tree*, but a *directed acyclic graph*, and this usually allows for a rather simple dynamic programming approaches.

Comment: you assume that he doesn't make any computations when traversing, and that's may be not true

Comment: @avim, I guess it should be rather heavy computation to outweight output. Anyway, this will not lead to asymptotically better solution; moreover, if that's the case, than OP should definitely mention this in the question, because the question will be not "how to optimize traversal", but "how to optimize computations".

Comment: @Petr even without actually printing the result it takes a lot of time. It seems possible to save some time because if I already visited in a specific subtree and visited in all his sub-paths then I shouldn't do it again.

Comment: @Kfozli, even if your remove output (but output only), it will still be `O(R)` with `R` the total length of all paths, because you still have to walk each of those paths. "if I already visited in a specific subtree and visited in all his sub-paths then I shouldn't do it again" --- then you do not print or do not enumerate all the possible paths, as you leave some of them out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every node represents a unique subtree rooted at that node and set of node values is not much big, you could use this to optimise traversal:

```
string s[MAX_NODE_VALUE + 1];

string post_traverse(Node root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return "";
    if(s[root.value].length() == 0)
    {
        s[root.value] += post_traverse(root.left);
        s[root.value] += post_traverse(root.right);
        s[root.value] += itoa(root.value);
        s[root.value] += ' ';
    }
    cout << s[root.value];
    return s[root.value];
}
```

This will only help when you have too many repeated subtrees and set of node values is very small, otherwise it will consume too much space and take more time.